# Want to change a logo with an if/then condition

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I want to select a logo depending on a check box of a page property I have added via extension. The variable *selectcompany* is shown correctly when dumping the variables.

I am running Typo3 8 LTS.

```
obj.logo {
  <f:if condition="{field:selectcompany}==1">
    <f:then>
      file = fileadmin/template/private/images/Logo1.png
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      file = fileadmin/template/private/images/Logo0.png
    </f:else>
  </f:if>    
}
```

Although the variable is set correctly, always Logo0.png is displayed. When the variable is set to 1, I expected Logo1.png.

Comment: "page property added via extension" means you added a field to tha pages table?

Comment: Yes. There is a field named *selectcompany* and it is verified that it is working correctly.

Comment: So with a `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` it should be listed, right?. Shouldn't it be just `{selectcompany}` instead of `{field:selectcompany}` then?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly shown in debug. What puzzles me is that I have another code like `NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuright{field:rightmenucheckbox}">|</li>` and this just works. I essentially want the same with the logo filename. Just add 0 or 1 to the name and that would be it.

Comment: Ok now I've seen it: you are mixing up TypoScript code and fluid :) Look at the answer of Jo Hasenau and use the "if" construct in TypoScript or use the fluid "if" syntax in your template, you can't mix them. The example with `wrapItemAndSub` works because you are using `insertData` I guess. But, again, this is plain TypoScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On TypoScript, it is possible to use a condition (TYPO3 9.5.x syntax):

```
[page["selectcompany"] == 1]
  obj.logo.file= fileadmin/Images/logo1.png 
[GLOBAL]
```

Else, you could solve with fluid templating; it should be just:

```
  <f:if condition="{data.selectcompany}">
    <f:then>
      <f:image src="fileadmin/template/private/images/Logo1.png" alt="" />  
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <f:image src="fileadmin/template/private/images/Logo0.png" alt="" />  
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
```

I used `<f:image>` but I guess you could also go with a plain `<img>` tag, too.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a TypoScript snippet, you can not fill in a Fluid condition there, but have to make use of the TypoScript variant of an if condition.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html